# German language equivalent for "beta" software?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What are the most common terms used by the software industry in German to list software as "beta" as in an early release. And how would they translate literally to American English?

Beta software defined as not officially released but available to a select number of individuals for testing.
https://techterms.com/definition/beta_software

While there might be some phrases, I am looking for the short version which would be easily recognizable.

Comment: The common term in German is *Beta-Version*. We also have the word *Beta-Tester*.

Comment: And of course *beta* is a greek letter needing no special effort to be imported into German the same way as it found in chemistry, statistics, ...

Answer (score 6):

Die Ausdrücke Betasoftware, Betaversion und Betastadium sind auch die in Deutschland üblichen.

Software/Programme in der Testphase oder im Versuchsstadium wären aber Ausdrücke, die auch kein Stirnrunzeln hervorrufen würden und zu denen man greifen könnte, wenn man sich darum bemüht, Anglizismen zu vermeiden, ohne hölzern zu klingen.

Englisch: Programs in the test phase or at the experimental stage.

Comment: Beta-Version ist definitiv sehr üblich im Deutschen. Bedient man sich jedoch bei einem anderen Feld der Industrie, nämlich bei den Medien, speziell der Produktion von Zeitschriften, dann findet man dort auch den Ausdruck ***Null-Nummer***. Das ist eine allererste Ausgabe einer Zeitschrift, die zum Testen des gesamten Ablaufs der Produktion, der Graphik und natürlich der journalistischen Arbeit als solcher dient. Darauf gestützt fände ich es angemessen, auch bei Software von einer Null-Nummer (statt Beta-Version) zu sprechen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ich fürchte allerdings, dass im IT-Umfeld Fachterminologie der Printmedien unbekannt ist und die [Nullnummer](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nullnummer) im der Bedeutung 3 als unnütz oder Flop verstanden wird.

Comment: @Stephie.  Ja, ich war ja nur am Tagträumen...